# Find sum of rows with entries more than a value in R

Tags: r

I have following matrix:

```
m = structure(1:20, .Dim = 4:5)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
>
```

I want to find sum of entries in every row for entry value more than 5.

I can only do it after converting to data.frame and with 2 'for' loops.

```
ddf = data.frame(m)

ddf
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  5  9 13 17
2  2  6 10 14 18
3  3  7 11 15 19
4  4  8 12 16 20

for(i in 1:nrow(ddf)){
    dsum=0
    for(j in 1:ncol(ddf)){
        if(ddf[i,j] > 5) dsum = dsum+ddf[i,j]
    }
    print(dsum)
}

[1] 39
[1] 48
[1] 52
[1] 56
```

Is there any other more elegant method?

Comment: `apply( m , 1 , function(x) sum(x[x>5]) )`

Comment: @Andrie: rowSums(m[m>5])  does not work. Error in rowSums(m[m > 5])  :  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon: OK. It's very basic. Thanks.

Comment: the (elegant) solution was `rowSums(m*(m>5))` not `rowSums(m[m>5])`. `m[m>5]` collapses your matrix into a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this using `rowSums()` with some subsetting, or with matrix multiplication

The first solution: Using `rowSums()`:

```
rowSums(m*(m>5))
[1] 39 48 52 56
```

This works because:

```
m>5
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE


m*(m>5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    9   13   17
[2,]    0    6   10   14   18
[3,]    0    7   11   15   19
[4,]    0    8   12   16   20
```

---

The second solution, using matrix math:

```
diag(m %*% t(m>5))
[1] 39 48 52 56
```

---

And if all else fails, do it the `apply` way:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x)sum(x[x>5]))
[1] 39 48 52 56
```